# Does Lightning Professional give access to Salesforce DX, COA and Enviroment Hub?

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, userlicense, environment-hub

We want certain users to have access to Salesforce DX, some to have access to Channel Order App (COA) and some to Salesforce Environment Hub. We wanted to know if buying Lightning Professional licenses for them will give them access to each or combination of these 3 apps/modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Dev hub is supported only in Enterprise and Unlimited Edition orgs, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_hub_intro.htm).

> Available in: Lightning Experience
>
> Available in: **Enterprise** and
> **Unlimited** Editions

Note that Salesforce licenses are always all the same license type as the organization itself. For example, if you're an Enterprise Org, any licenses you buy for Salesforce users must also be Enterprise. You wouldn't be able to buy Professional Licenses.

Salesforce DX is just software, can be used by anyone, and only needs normal developer permissions (e.g. Author Apex to deploy code). COA can be granted access to anyone that you'd like as well.

Comment: Ours is an Enterprise Edition so does that mean we can only purchase and assign "Lightning Enterprise" licenses for our users from the available options [here](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/)?

Comment: @Prathmesh Correct. You cannot purchase Professional Licenses in an Enterprise Org. And this the minimum version supported for Scratch Orgs, at any rate. Unfortunately, developers are no less expensive than administrators or normal users.

Comment: Thanks for info. Just a follow up,
Also I was inquiring about the Environment Hub which the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205660&type=1) says
Only Platform and Standard Salesforce licensed users can access the Environment Hub.
So finally, can Lightning Enterprise license give my users access to DX+COA+Env Hub ?

Comment: @Prathmesh Yes, Standard Salesforce License in your case means anyone that's an Enterprise Edition user (i.e. is not a Community, Chatter, or Portal user).